# Error graph $(x^2+y^2)*\exp(-x^2-y^2)$

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to graph with tikz [image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.5\linewidth,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
        ]
        \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:1,domain y=-1:1]
        {((x^2+y^2)*\exp(-x^2-y^2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it is wrong, why?

Comment: There is no macro`\exp` you want the function `exp`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Oh estimable @hpekristiansen thank so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code emended and completed:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.5\linewidth,
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
        ]
        \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
        {((x^2+y^2)*exp(-x^2-y^2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]